# How can I write expression to take an subtraction of two fields in ssrs?

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I'm working on SSRS report.

There are two main fields `CurrentMV` and `PreviousMV`.

field `CurrentMV` having expression `=Sum(Fields!CurrentMV.Value)`

field `PreviousMV` having expression `=Previous(Sum(Fields!CurrentMV.Value))`

I'm having another field on report `MTM` which is nothing but difference between

`CurrentMV- PreviousMV` How can I write expression for `MTM` as there is already expression used in `CurrentMV` and `PreviousMV`

please help me.

Comment: `=Sum(Fields!CurrentMV.Value)-Previous(Sum(Fields!CurrentMV.Value))` ? or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: I would worried will this work in all the cases?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand your question. If the other formulas product the expect result then this one will.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`=Sum(Fields!CurrentMV.Value)-Previous(Sum(Fields!CurrentMV.Value))` ? or am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 3):

`=Sum(Fields!CurrentMV.Value) - Previous(Sum(Fields!CurrentMV.Value))`?